# Angular Cancel Tabset click

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I'm creating my tabset dynamically with an ng-repeat. Within the tab is a dynamic form. When the user clicks a tab the controller calls $state.go() and loads the data for the next form.  We recently had a requirement to check if the form had unsaved changes and prompt the user.  I found https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges which does the job great.  The problem I'm running into is when the user clicks cancel the selected tab remains on the new tab they clicked.

My tabs are created like:

```
 <div tabset style="align-content: center;">
      <div tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.Tabs" heading="{{ tab.Name }}" active="$first" select="onTabSelect(tab.RecordID)">
      </div>
 </div>
```

In the controller when they choose the next tab:

```
$scope.onTabSelect = function (tabId) {
        $state.go('app.Tabs.TabRender', {
            recordID: tabId,
        });
    };
```

I modified the unsavedChanges service to broadcast when the user clicks cancel and can capture that in my controller correctly.  The only issue I'm having is how do I reset the selected tab back to the original tab?

Comment: Solved this by adding an active property to each tab object and setting that in the controller based on if the user was redirected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding an active property to each tab object and setting that in the controller based on if the user was redirected or not.

```
<div tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.Tabs" heading="{{ tab.Name }}" active="tab.Active" select="onTabSelect(tab.RecordID)">
```

and in the controller:

```
    function setActiveTab(id) {
        _.each(vm.Tabs, function (tab) {
            if (tab.RecordID === id)
                tab.active = true;
            else
                tab.active = false;
        });
    }

    $scope.$on("redirectCancelled", function () {
        setActiveTab(currentTab);
    });

    $scope.$on("resetResettables", function () {
        currentTab = redirectTab;
    });

    $scope.onTabSelect = function (tabId) {
        redirectTab = tabId;
        setActiveTab(tabId);

        $state.go('app.Tabs.TabRender', {
            recordID: tabId,
        });            
    };
```